# Importing tensorflow not working when upgraded

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

`Tensorflow` was working fine when I had `1.4` but when I upgraded it, it stopped working.

The version that I installed is `1.11` with `CUDA 9` and `cuDNN 7`.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py",
>   line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py",
>   line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File
>   "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py",
>   line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py",
>   line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall the tensorflow and re-install it.